# Android table row image

Tags: android, image, view

How do I make an image occupy the entire row of a table and not be bigger than the screen ?

```
TableLayout tableView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblVW);
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);       
ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
bmp=getbmp(img);
im.setImageBitmap(bmp);      
row.addView(im);
tableView.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

If I use this code , the image is bigger than the screen . I want the image to fill the whole row , regardless the view ( landscape or portrait) or the device's screen size.

Comment: better to use in xml coding for this.